# WebEdit Button for External Link? (Sitecore 7.2)

Tags: richtext-editor

I know how to add additional buttons to the WebEdit Toolbar for Rich Text fields when in Page Editor (chromecontrol.js _maxToolbarCommands for lenght, fieldchrometype.js for additional case statement for handleMessage) but I am not sure what command to use to do something similar to the "Hyperlink Manager" button that is available in the RTE when in Content Editor.

Direction or link to a blog post would be appreciated - my googling came up empty but I can't be the first person that needs to give the business user the ability to link to an external link from Page Editor.